# Error while deploying the SAPUI5 application inside the ABAP repository

Tags: deployment, sap-web-ide, web-ide

I have a UI5 application.

When I am trying to deploy it in my ABAP repository it shows the following errors:

> (SAPUI5 ABAP Repository) Updating of file in MIME Repository failed:
>   manifest-bundle.zip

How can I solve it?

For it seems when users with different default languages work on the same project it happen. For example I have set my browser on English and my colleagues on German. Any idea or same experiences is appreciated.

[image: View of the error in WEBIDE console]

Comment: Hi Mahdi, quick question why you trying to deploy zip file to bsp app? Is it mandatory to have a zip file in project?

Comment: I am not trying. It is an automated created file by the WEBIDE.

Comment: I even tested the solutions that have been suggested here:
https://answers.sap.com/questions/607182/updating-of-file-in-mime-repository-failed-manifes.html
But seems non of the solutions are helpful except if I remove the application from ABAP repository and redeploy again. (Also my i18n files is just some kilobytes so the reason that Michal Keidar mentioned there is not the reason of this error. It seems when people who are working on app have different languages in their browser this problem will happen.)

Comment: Sorry to ask stupid question but have you tried the below as it suggest in the post you provided?

Hi All,

I found the solution for the problem.

1.implement the note 2685863.

2. Delete the app from ABAP gateway(BSP application)

3. Redeploy

4. for now on you will have no problem.

Comment: This is what I actually said before, I don't want and I cannot delete the App from the repository all the time and deploy again. Yes that can be the last solution. But I am looking for the reason to prevent it.

Comment: Hi may be you can try get the git project zip file and upload directly as referred in link below:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832154/deploy-application-to-sap-abap-repository-from-webide-with-larger-size

Then make a change in webide and try deploying again and see what happens

Comment: This zip file contains the translation files. and it is just 2 KB. So the timeout problem for uploading a huge file is not the reason of this error. To be honest I would like to know what is the reason behind. Because this problem starts when one of my colleagues with a browser with default language of German tried to deploy his changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as described in [this topic](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_uiaddon20/2.05/en-US/9e/6305746b8742f69faa55fae27ee220/content.htm?no_cache=true)

> Each file in the layered repository has a master language. The master language is the same as the logon language of the user who has created the file (for example, a variant). If the file is changed later on, you can **only change** the file in that **specific language**.

So, if the application was deployed in *english* version of chrome, then you can deploy **manifest-bundle.zip** only from *english* chrome version

Comment: So it means the language of the browser must be set same as what we deployed the first time!

Comment: @MahdiJ.Ansari, correct. Then you can succesfull deploy the application to ABAP repository without problem with MIME-Repository.